# Jpa criteria, convert enum type to string

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, criteria

i got some problem. I created entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Trace extends AbstractEntity {

@Column(name = "trace_level")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TraceLevel traceLevel;

...
}
```

And jpa criteria:

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
tempList.add("Warning");
Path path = root.get("traceLevel");
Predicate inP = path.in(tempList);
```

Of course i got problem

```
Parameter value [Warning] did not match expected type [com.getknowledge.platform.modules.trace.trace.level.TraceLevel (n/a)]
```

Since the data for the filter come from the client, and are processed at the basic level, the transformation in string to enum i can not do. The question is, can i build query using strings.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to transform the string into an enum? Just use TraceLevel.valueOf()

Answer (score 0):

Every `enum` has a function `valueOf` that takes a `String` and returns the appropriate constant. So instead of

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
tempList.add("Warning");
```

use

```
List<TraceLevel> tempList=new ArrayList<>();
tempList.add(TraceLevel.valueOf("Warning"));
```

Comment: I don't know enum type in runtime. Cause I get json list string from client